# requests post to imgur

Tags: python, http, python-requests, imgur

```
from oauth_hook import OAuthHook
import requests, json
OAuthHook.consumer_key = "KEYHERE" 
OAuthHook.consumer_secret = "SECRET HERE"
oauth_hook = OAuthHook("TOKEN_KEY_HERE", "TOKEN_SECRET_HERE", header_auth=True)
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
client = requests.session(hooks={'pre_request': oauth_hook}, headers=headers)
payload = {"title":"album title"}
r = client.post("http://api.imgur.com/2/account/albums.json",payload)
print r.text
```

This should create an album with the title `album title` how instead the return string is

```
{
    "albums": {
        "id": "IMGURID",
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "privacy": "public",
        "cover": "",
        "order": 0,
        "layout": "blog",
        "datetime": "2012-12-05 15:48:21",
        "link": "IMGUR LINK",
        "anonymous_link": "ANONYLINK"
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a solution for setting the album title using requests?

here is a link to the imgur API docs http://api.imgur.com/resources_auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not posting JSON data; instead it'll be converted to URL-encoded data instead. `requests` does not provide automatic JSON encoding, even if you do set the content type to `application/json`.

Use the `json` module to encode:

```
import json

r = client.post("http://api.imgur.com/2/account/albums.json", json.dumps(payload))
```

You can see this when using the [`http://httpbin/post` POST echo service](http://httpbin.org/):

```
>>> import json, requests, pprint
>>> headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
>>> payload = {"title":"album title"}
>>> pprint.pprint(requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', payload, headers=headers).json)
{u'args': {},
 u'data': u'title=album+title',
 u'files': {},
 u'form': {},
 u'headers': {u'Accept': u'*/*',
              u'Accept-Encoding': u'gzip, deflate, compress',
              u'Connection': u'keep-alive',
              u'Content-Length': u'17',
              u'Content-Type': u'application/json',
              u'Host': u'httpbin.org',
              u'User-Agent': u'python-requests/0.14.2 CPython/2.7.3 Darwin/11.4.2'},
 u'json': None,
 u'origin': u'xx.xx.xx.xx',
 u'url': u'http://httpbin.org/post'}
>>> pprint.pprint(requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', json.dumps(payload), headers=headers).json)
{u'args': {},
 u'data': u'{"title": "album title"}',
 u'files': {},
 u'form': {},
 u'headers': {u'Accept': u'*/*',
              u'Accept-Encoding': u'gzip, deflate, compress',
              u'Connection': u'keep-alive',
              u'Content-Length': u'24',
              u'Content-Type': u'application/json',
              u'Host': u'httpbin.org',
              u'User-Agent': u'python-requests/0.14.2 CPython/2.7.3 Darwin/11.4.2'},
 u'json': {u'title': u'album title'},
 u'origin': u'xx.xx.xx.xx',
 u'url': u'http://httpbin.org/post'}
```

If you are using `requests` version 2.4.2 or newer, you can leave the encoding to the library; simply pass in the payload as the `json` keyword argument; incidentally it'll also set the correct Content-Type header in that case:

```
r = client.post("http://api.imgur.com/2/account/albums.json", json=payload)
```

Comment: Just url encoding the payload fails to make any difference, it should work but it doesn't

Comment: @lab_notes: There could be *other* problems too, but not encoding JSON properly is the first of them then.